# Get the group of the current user using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, rest

I'm trying to get the group of current user.
By using this code:

```
function checkGroup() {
    var group = ["D", "Sup", "A", "CP"];
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
        if (isMember(group[i]) == true)
        {

            alert('I am a member of the group'+ i);
            break;
        }
    }

}    

function isMember(groupName){
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getByName('"+groupName+"')/Users?$filter=Id eq " + _spPageContextInfo.userId,
        method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"},
    success: function (data) {
        alert('I am a member of the group' + groupName);
        return true;

    },
    error: function (data) {
        return false;

    },
        asyn:false,
    });
}
```

the problem is , it always return true , means i the member of all group which is false .

Any idea ??

Comment: You could've used this if you set async to false (an option inside $.ajax({ }) and returned a variable with true or false. I'm not recommending it though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to determine whether *current users belongs to the specified groups*:

```
getCurrentUserWithDetails()
.done(function(data)
{
    var groupNames = ['News Owners','Approvers'];
    //determine wether current user is a memeber of group(s) 
    var userGroups = data.d.Groups.results;
    var foundGroups = userGroups.filter(function(g){ return groupNames.indexOf(g.LoginName) > -1});

})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

where `getCurrentUserWithDetails` function is used to get current user with groups:

```
function getCurrentUserWithDetails()
{
    var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + '/_api/web/currentuser/?$expand=groups';
    return $.ajax({
            url: endpointUrl,
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {   
             "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            } 
        });
}
```

> Key points: more optimal from performance perspective since only a
>   **single** request is submitted to the server

Comment: Vadim, will this work if the current logged in user is in an Active Directory Group residing in a SharePoint Group?

Comment: @Bismarck, unfortunately no, AD Group is treated as a user in SharePoint and therefore AD Group needs to be "expanded"

Comment: how to check whether the current logged in user belongs to a single or multiple group(s), where the groupname  starts with "ABC" , like "ABC HR", "ABC Sales" , "ABC Finance" ,, etc..

Comment: Thanks for the `/_api/web/currentuser` endpoint. Didn't know it.

Comment: Can one use `'/_api/web/getuserbyid(' + userid + ')/?$expand=groups'` to get the groups of any user?

Comment: How can we get the SharePoint group of a user if user is added through an AD group to that SP group?

Answer (score -2):

You can get current Loggedin user's name using below code as well.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
    var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
    });

    function onSuccess(data, request) {
        var Logg = data.d;
        //get login name
        var loginName = Logg.LoginName.split('|')[1];
        alert(loginName);
        //get display name
        alert(Logg.Title);
    }

    function onError(error) {
        alert("error");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks hardik , im not looking for the the current user name or login name , but the group of the current user ?

Comment: We need the current users group, not the current users login name