# how to check if user exist in two groups rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using below rest api call to check if user exist in Admin group but how to check if user exist in more then one group ex Admin and Member group

```
url: absoluteUri + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getByName('Admin ')/Users?$filter=Id eq " + _spPageContextInfo.userId,
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either do a foreach-statement to check multiple groups (one at the time) or to it the other way around - get a users group membership and then loop through the results.

The user Vadim Gremyachev has added an excellent answer of to handle this here: [Get the group of the current user using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137303/get-the-group-of-the-current-user-using-rest-api)

I'm quoting his full answer here:

> The following example demonstrates how to determine whether current
> users belongs to the specified groups:
>
> ```
> getCurrentUserWithDetails()
> .done(function(data)
> {
>     var groupNames = ['News Owners','Approvers'];
>     //determine wether current user is a memeber of group(s) 
>     var userGroups = data.d.Groups.results;
>     var foundGroups = userGroups.filter(function(g){ return groupNames.indexOf(g.LoginName) > -1});
>
> })
> .fail(
> function(error){
>     console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
> });
> ```
>
> where getCurrentUserWithDetails function is used to get current user
> with groups:
>
> ```
> function getCurrentUserWithDetails()
> {
>     var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + '/_api/web/currentuser/?$expand=groups';
>     return $.ajax({
>             url: endpointUrl,
>             method: "GET",
>             contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
>             headers: {   
>              "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
>             } 
>         });
> }
> ```
>
> Key points: more optimal from performance perspective since only a
> single request is submitted to the server

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved through graph Api.

if you want to lists the group which user is member of.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/memberOf
```

if you want get count of group a user is member

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/memberOf/$count
```

You can find further details on this referring below Microsoft docs

- [List memberOf](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

Can be acheaved by REST API too,

get the all groups that user belongs to:

```
"/_api/web/GetUserById(" + userId + ")/Groups"
```

in function:

```
GetUserGroups = function(userId){
    var Id = _spPageContextInfo.userId
    if (typeof userId != 'undefined' && userId!=""){
        Id = userId;
    }
    var result = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetUserById(" + Id + ")/Groups",  
        method: "GET",   
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(data){
            result = data.d.results
        }
    })
    return result;
}
```